# Sum of a Series With Denominators of the form $(2^i) (3^j)(5^k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can anyone solve this?

Find the sum of the series  $1 + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}+ \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots,$ where the denominators are of the form $(2^i) (3^j)(5^k)$?

The test came with the next answer choices:

a) $\frac{7}{2}$

b) $1$

c) $3$

d) $\frac{15}{4}$

e) $\frac{3}{2}$

I thought this would tend to infinity. Maybe the test answer choices were wrong..

Comment: Question is unclear. Please update appropriately.

Comment: @Aniket: I believe the series is $$\sum_{i\geq0,j\geq0,k\geq0}2^{-i}3^{-j}5^{-k}$$

Comment: @MPW What about the summation of harmonic series the OP is talking of?

Comment: @Aniket: Look carefully, this is NOT a harmonic series. Each term shown is of the form I mentioned. Note that, for example, $\frac17$ is not present.

Comment: @Aniket: The terms shown are $$1/2^03^05^0 + 1/2^13^05^0 + 1/2^03^15^0 + 1/2^23^05^0 + 1/2^03^05^1 + 1/2^13^15^0 + 1/2^33^05^0 + 1/2^03^25^0 \cdots$$

Comment: @MPW Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @YuriyS: Someone edited the original question incorrectly after I commented. I will repair it. $\frac17$ is definitely *not* supposed to be there. You see the title of the question, right? And the description of the denominators in the question body?

Comment: @MPW, I absolutely agree with you. I just wanted to point it out

Comment: @YuriyS: Okay, thanks, I understand. If you go into the edit history, you can see where the error was introduced.

Answer (score 14):

Consider $$(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^n} + \ldots)(1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \ldots + \frac{1}{3^n} + \ldots)(1 + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{25} + \ldots + \frac{1}{5^n} + \ldots)$$

Answer (score 2):

We have an [Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product):
$$ \prod_{p\leq 5}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1} = \prod_{p\leq 5}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^2}+\ldots \right) = \sum_{n\in A}\frac{1}{n} $$
where $A$ is the set of positive integers whose prime divisors are $\leq 5$.

It follows that our series equals:
$$ 2\cdot \frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{4} = \color{red}{\frac{15}{4}}.$$